# Fractal strings of Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, soft-question

I am teaching myself what fractal strings are. From my understanding it is a bounded open subset of the real line. Wiki goes on to say that the string comes associated with at most countably many lengths say $l_1,l_2,...$ (associated to connected open intervals). It then goes on to say the fractal string for the Cantor set is $\{1/3,1/9,1/9,...\}$ would the next one also be $1/9$ then $1/27$? So would it be counting up the legths of the open intervals between the breaks? so if $C_0=[0,1]$ Then the first stage we get $C_1=[0,1/3] \cup [2/3,1]$ thus the middle has length $1/3$. And next stage we have three intervals in between so it would be $1/9$ three times? And does every fractal string naturally come with an associated zeta function whose poles form a sequence of complex numbers called complex dimensions? This was formulated rigorously first by Michel Lapidus. I was reading up on his fractal zeta function text and saw fractal string being thrown around a lot I'd like to grasp the concept well. So could one have complex fractal strings as well as real? Thanks in advance sorry if this is a soft question. Also idk if this question makes sense but do fractal strings typically consist of discrete sets as apposed to continuous? (in the sense that standard metric is a continuous set whereas the $p-$adic metric forms a discrete set).